# Margins reverse left and right

Tags: margins

I am using `geometry` package to set different page margins on the right and left side of my thesis. Please see the relevant code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf[pages=-]{thesisTitlepage} % this is a doble-side title page
\end{titlepage}

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty} % this page is on 3rd page
\par\vspace*{.35\textheight}{\Large\itshape some deep loving words.}

\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments} % this page is on 4th page
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Abstract}
...
\clearpage

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap1introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

...
\end{document}
```

From the Acknowledgments chapter, the margins were reversed left and right. Can anyone please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you want `\cleardoublepage` after the title page.

Comment: Or, add the document class option `openright`. That way, each chapter will start on a recto (right-hand-side, odd-numbered) page. The `openright` option is enabled by default for the `book` document class but not for the `report` document class.

Comment: @egreg did you mean to replace the `\clearpage` right before `\chapter{Introduction}` by `\cleardoublepage`. If so, it makes an empty page with page heading and page number, which was not desirable. If replacing that right after 
`\end{titlepage}` by `\cleardoublepage`, it seems of no effect... please help

Comment: @jsxs If you want the abstract page to be on the back of the title page, then OK; however, the change in numbering confuses the margins. Issue `\cleardoublepage` before `\chapter{Introduction}`, which will put things in sync. You will get a blank page if the front matter ends with an odd numbered page.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, please see my update, which is the real code. The problem remains but in another place. Please note that the title page is a double-side title page, followed by a dedication.

Comment: I think the issue is that you have `twoside` set in your options, so the margins are reversed every other page. Perhaps delete `twoside`. Add `showframe` to your `geometry` options, and you can see it better.